# How can I create a package of a PyQt/PySide application which can be expected to run in "reasonable" environments?

Tags: python, deployment, pyqt, pyside

By "reasonable" environment I mean that it should not require the user to manually install any dependencies of the application, but a working Python installation can be required. Additionally I would like the application to work on Windows, OSX, and popular Linux distributions. If I can package a Python interpreter as well, that's better. Size is not really a concern. A good example of what I want to accomplish is the SublimeText editor.

Is there an established way of doing this?

Comment: @Downvoter, please explain.

Comment: I just upvoted this question and I would appreciate a more complete answer... not finding much by Google.

Comment: Thank you. I still haven't found a good way. The upvoted answer is not what the question is about.

Comment: py2exe will create the app with pyside/pyqt just fine. However, the trick would be packaging the QT libraries (no PyQt or PySide). Any ideas on this?

Comment: Classic "what tool can I use for X" question that is not apt for SO.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, python comes with setup utilities, and there are packages which will put your complete application in a platform specific binary(exe on windows, .app on osx).
Some of the packages I would recommend looking at would be:

cx_freeze

py2app

py2exe

Comment: Thanks. Any ideas for packaging the Qt runtime / libs? They are not part of Python so I doubt this works alone.

Comment: You can add those through the setup procedure, read the documentation about python setuptools, you can package those along with the packages.